# Bind color of SolidColorBrush to background color of Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a custom rounded button with following code But the color button doesn't follow the Background property of button so i have to create new style for each color of button.

How can i bind SolidColorBrush Color to Button Background color ?

```
        <Style x:Key="RoundedButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="BUTTON BACKGROUND"/>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Button's Background is already a Brush. No need to create another one:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will probably have to use a one way [DataBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview)